# array equalizer by multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers

given set of three numbers and an array of numbers. we can multiply the values in array any number of times by the numbers in set of three numbers. how to detect at any point of time all values in array will be equal or not.
ex. three numbers- [a ,b , c]
array = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 5, 6,7]
now we can multiply every value in array any number of times by a , b, c. at any time will the values in the array be equalized or not? what is the condition for that. The three numbers can be any numbers and array can be any array.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this you need to look at the prime factorisation. So the array of three numbers should contain the unique prime factors of the numbers of the other array. However if some prime(s) only occurs as a common factor raised to some power(s), than that factor can be used as well in the first array. For example 12 and 144, which is $2^2\times3$ and $(2^2\times3)^2$.

In your example there are more prime factors that three, so there will be no solution.